# Android casting double to int results in Zero always

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert a double value to an int (right now don't care if it rounds or drops the decimal).

I have tried many method and searched and I always get the same result, the int is 0.

```
for(double time=1;time<100; time++){
  Double sin = Double.valueOf(Math.sin(freq*time*2*Math.PI)/Math.exp(decay*time));
  BigDecimal sinBD = new BigDecimal(sin);

  int nowProgress = lastProgress* sinBD.intValue();
  Log.d("touch", "Time: " + time + " - BOUNCE PROGRESS: " + nowProgress + " SIN:" + sin + " " + sin.intValue()  );
  publishProgress(nowProgress);
}
```

Output is:

```
D/touch   (  405): Time: 92.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:-5.650622119921064E-54 0
D/touch   (  405): Time: 93.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:-2.9583499774959883E-54 0
D/touch   (  405): Time: 94.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:2.9429214663931283E-55 0
D/touch   (  405): Time: 95.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:-1.0777191865157576E-56 0
D/touch   (  405): Time: 96.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:-4.775752566124532E-56 0
D/touch   (  405): Time: 97.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:-3.367948939041307E-56 0
D/touch   (  405): Time: 98.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:-1.8316705209724932E-56 0
D/touch   (  405): Time: 99.0 - BOUNCE PROGRESS: 0 SIN:2.577602055706179E-57 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `sin` values are very small numbers (very near to 0), so when you cast them to `int` you will get `0`.

Note that the notation `xxxE-yy` is another representation of `xxx * Math.pow(10, -yy)`

**Edit:**

Also, make sure that `lastProgress` is not `0`.

Comment: and/or `lastProgress` is `0` (Your answer is correct, that may just be the next problem)

Comment: That's another possibility. OP please try printing `lastProgress` and see if you get `0`.

Comment: No, `lastProgress` doesn't matter for the value of `sin` or `sin.intValue()`. The values of `sin` are shown, they vary, and they are extremely low (-5.650622119921064E-54).

Comment: @his The main problem are the `sin` values. But `lastProgress` could **also** be a problem.

Comment: It is not a problem in regard to this question (which is why a _minimal_ code sample would have been better).

Comment: I feel like an idiot, just realized my numbers actual value....

Time to go back to highschool math for me.....

Comment: @user3211352 If it makes you feel any better, we **all** make these mistakes :) Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes.